# how to backup remote AWS RDS mariaDB server to local direcotry using xtrabackup

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds, percona

I am using xtrabackup to backup remote MariaDB from AWS RDS like this:

```
xtrabackup --host=xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 --backup --databases=test --import=xxxxxx.sql --user=root --password=xxxxxx --target-dir=s3://xxxx/xxxxxx/
```

but the result is:

```
Using server version 10.2.21-MariaDB-log
Warning: option 'datadir' points to nonexistent directory '/var/lib/mysql'
Warning: MySQL variable 'datadir' points to nonexistent directory '/rdsdbdata/db/'
Warning: option 'datadir' has different values:
  '/var/lib/mysql' in defaults file
  '/rdsdbdata/db/' in SHOW VARIABLES
xtrabackup version 2.4.4 based on MySQL server 5.7.13 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: df58cf2)
xtrabackup: uses posix_fadvise().
xtrabackup: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
xtrabackup: cannot my_setwd /var/lib/mysql
```

what should I do to fix this? As I am not trying to store the backup on the local directory why is it looking for /var/lib/mysql?